# Obtain page data and use regular loop

Tags: loop, 404-error, get-post

Is there a way to obtain the data from a certain page outside the regular flow, more efficiently than via `get_post($id)`?
I know that I can get for example the title with

```
$post = get_post($id);
$title = $post->post_title;
```

But I prefer to use the loop, rather than picking every single page element in the way I described above.
So what I want, is to read the entire page data, and then perform a 'regular loop', using `the_title()`, `the_content()`, `the_post_thumbnail()` etc.

The reason why I ask this is because I'm busy creating a '404 solution' for my theme, where one is able to create and edit a custom 404 page in the WordPress backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`setup_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata).

```
$post = get_post( $id );
setup_postdata( $post );

if(! empty( $post ) ){
  the_title(); 
  echo '<br>';
  the_content();
}
else {
  echo "No page found matching ID $id";
}
```